# How to set a class of mathematical functions in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, class

I would like to create a math-visualisation class in Python where I can visualise optimisation algorithms. This is what I have so far:

```
class function_visualisation:
    def objective1n1(x):
        return x**5.0 - 2*x**4 - 0.5*x**3 + 4*x**2 - x

    def objective2n1(x,y):
        return x**5.0 - 2*y**4 - 15*x**3 + 4*y**2 - x

    def __init__(self, input = 0):
        self.fct_1 = self.objective1n1(x)
        self.fct_2 = self.objective2n1(x,y)
```

Where right now I have 2 polynomials; the first taking one and the second two inputs.
Eventually I would like the class to have several adjustable function types and plotting methods. The problem is that when trying to instanciate Python says

```
    self.fct_1 = self.objective1n1(x)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

which I can understand.

In various posts I saw people use an intuitive technique to define functions with numpy; e.g. :

```
x = np.linspace(−4*np.pi,4*np.pi,50)

y = np.linspace(−4*np.pi,4*np.pi,50)

z = x**2 + y**2
```

Is there a good way to get something similar such that I don't have to give the function arguments in advance?

Edit:
Thanks to both of you.

but as I commented, when I initialise and insert a concrete value

```
fcts = function_visualisation()

print(fcts.fct_1(5))
```

I get

```
    print(fcts.fct_1(5))
TypeError: objective1n1() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

The reason I do want a class like this is to package different plotting methods for different dimensions together and make it easy to change the function one contemplates. So how could I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

`self.objective1n1(x)` is the call of the function `self.objective1n1`. If you simply want to change which function is behind `self.fct_1`, you need

```
self.fct_1 = self.objective1n1
```

If you don't need the self-reference, you can use the [`@staticmethod` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod). However, you might want to think about not using a class for this in the first place.

Comment: Uh thanks. But now I get
```print(fct.fct_1(5)) TypeError: objective1n1() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given```
when I initialize the class as ```fct = function_visualisation()```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a function, such as

```
def objective1n1(x):
    return x**5.0 - 2*x**4 - 0.5*x**3 + 4*x**2 - x
```

Calling `objective1n1(x)` will calculate this function at the input `x`, thus `x` has to be defined in advance (just like in your example with `np.linspace`).

If you simply want to assign a function object to another variable, use:

```
self.fct_1 = self.objective1n1
```

After that, you can call `self.fct_1(x)` for any `x` later in your code.

Answer (score 0):

To combine the answers of **Martin Thoma**, **Mikhail Genkin** and the comment of **kindall**:

Calling `objective1n1(x)` will calculate this function at the input `x`, thus `x` has to be defined in advance (just like in the example with `np.linspace`).

If one simply wants to assign a function object to another variable, use:

`self.fct_1 = self.objective1n1`

To be able to call the function like this

```
fcts = function_visualisation()

print(fcts.fct_1(5))
```

one has to define it either with a `@staticmethod` decorator

```
@staticmethod
def objective1n1(x):
    return x**5.0 - 2*x**4 - 0.5*x**3 + 4*x**2 - x
```

or with a `self` reference

```
def objective1n1(self,x):
    return x**5.0 - 2*x**4 - 0.5*x**3 + 4*x**2 - x
```